# Pascal: Updating Recent Scores Array

Tags: pascal

I have a program that stores the last three recent scores of a game.  However, I would like to  store only the best scores.  Eg. Recent Scores:  Tom - 12, Sam - 14, Sue - 16.   If i played the game and got a new score of 20, i would like it to store the new score of 20 (with name) and the other two scores of Sam and Sue ...thereby losing Tom.  (I'm not worried about order).

```
Const NoOfRecentScores = 3; 

TRecentScore = Record
                   Name : String;
                   Score : Integer;
                 End;
  TRecentScores = Array[1..NoOfRecentScores] of TRecentScore;

Var
  RecentScores : TRecentScores;
```

When i play the game, i call a procedure called UpdateRecentScores.  Here it is:

```
Procedure UpdateRecentScores(Var RecentScores : TRecentScores; Score : Integer);
  Var
    PlayerName : String;
    Count,count2 : Integer;
    FoundSpace : Boolean;
    MinMark,position: Integer;
    ScorePresent:boolean = false;
  Begin
    PlayerName := GetPlayerName;
    FoundSpace := False;
    Count :=1;

    While Not FoundSpace And (Count <= NoOfRecentScores)
      Do If RecentScores[Count].Name = ''
           Then FoundSpace := True
           Else Count := Count + 1;
```

Here is the part i am struggling with. If no score is previously entered, then i have to accept that the first entered score is going to be the minimum:

```
   If ScorePresent = False then
       begin
         MinMark:=Score;
         ScorePresent:=True;
         RecentScores[Count].Name := PlayerName;
         RecentScores[Count].Score := Score;
         writeln('Minimum Mark is: ',MinMark);
       end
```

...the problem with the above, however, is that if the first score is a very high score, that becomes my minimum score!

Below, i am simply saying that if the Score achieved is greater than the MinMark (i.e. the minimum score) then the score should be stored in the array.

```
   else if Score> MinMark then
      begin
        For count:= 1 to NoOfRecentScores do
          begin
            if RecentScores[count].score<Score then
             position:=count;
        RecentScores[position].Name := PlayerName;
        RecentScores[position].Score := Score;
      end;
      End;
end;
```

As you can see, i am trying to check what the MinMark is first of all.  Then, compare the score that i've just got with the MinMarker to see if it should be stored.

To clarify therefore, I want to save the **best** 3 scores and not recent scores.

Comment: What is the exact problem you are experiencing?

Comment: I am still getting the scores in the order i've played. For example, I played the game 3 times and the following scores were stored:  Tim - 14, Susan - 7, Derek - 12.  I then played the game a 4th time and got the result  Gemma - 9.  I was expecting my results to show Tim - 14, Gemma - 9, Derek - 12.  Note, Gemma scored higher than Susan, so Susan should disappear... but it doesn't do this. It simply shows the first three scores again and again...no matter how high i score!

Comment: Also, do you want to store the **best** or the **recent** scores? If you want to have both, please specify how exactly you want to choose whom to exclude.

Comment: I want to score the **best** scores over time...

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense now. Please edit your question to include the example and the best/recent clearness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store `n` best scores, it is convenient to order them from high to low.

Let us go with an example first.  Suppose you have the following four records: Tim - 14, Susan - 7, Don - 5, and Derek - 12.  Then the array will look like `[('Tim', 14), ('Derek', 12), ('Susan', 7), ('Don', 5)]`.

Now, what happens when Bert achieves a score of 9?  Turns out we just want to insert a pair in a sorted array, so that it becomes `[('Tim', 14), ('Derek', 12), ('Bert', 9), ('Susan', 7), ('Don', 5)]`. After that, we drop the last element.

If we have to modify the array in place, we find the position `pos` where to insert Bert (it is position `3`), then move everything in positions `pos..(n-1)` into positions `(pos+1)..n`, and after that, write Ben and his score to position `pos`.

Comment: Ok, i will try this.  In fact, i have a sort procedure later in my program which i can call to sort the scores.  How do i call a procedure which is declared later in my program then?  Is it             Procedure SortRecords;  Pass; ?

Comment: @user3396486: `Procedure SortRecords; Forward;`. Also, you won't have to sort the scores explicitly if your insertion maintains the sorted property.

Comment: Hallelujah...i think it works now... here is my solution below...   Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using such a small array (3 records), it's relatively simple. (If your array was considerably larger, you'd want to keep it sorted and use a faster means of locating the right position for it, but your array is extremely small.)

Let's say you now have three RecentScore records, containing Tim - 14, Susan - 7, Derek - 12.

You need to find out if there's a score lower than the one the user just attained by Gemma (9) which is in the `CurrentScore` record (type `TRecentScore`), and if so replace it with Gemma's name and score.

Here's a working console project (compiled and run in XE5):

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;
type
  TRecentScore = record
    Name: string;
    Score: Integer;
  end;
  TRecentScores = array of TRecentScore;

// Function to find lower score than the one we're trying to add.
// Returns the index of the next lower item if there is one, or
// -1 if there isn't one.
function FindLowerScore(Scores: TRecentScores; CheckScore: Integer): Integer;
var
  i: Integer;
  MinScore: Integer;                        // Lowest score found
begin
  Result := -1;                             // No index found
  MinScore := CheckScore;                   // Lowest score so far

  for i := Low(Scores) to High(Scores) do
    if Scores[i].Score < MinScore then      // Lower than CheckScore?
    begin
      MinScore := Scores[i].Score;          // Yep. Store it (new lowest)
      Result := i;                          // and where it was found
    end;
end;

// Utility procedure to display list of scores
procedure PrintScores(const Prelude: string; Scores: TRecentScores);
var
  Score: TRecentScore;
begin
  WriteLn(Prelude);
  for Score in Scores do
    Writeln('   ' + Score.Name + ' = ' + IntToStr(Score.Score));
end;

var
  RecentScores: TRecentScores;
  CurrentScore: TRecentScore;
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(RecentScores, 3);

  RecentScores[0].Name := 'Tim'; 
  RecentScores[0].Score := 14;
  RecentScores[1].Name := 'Susan'; 
  RecentScores[1].Score := 7;
  RecentScores[2].Name := 'Derek';  
  RecentScores[2].Score := 12;

  // Show scores where we begin
  PrintScores('Before', RecentScores);

  CurrentScore.Name := 'Gemma'; CurrentScore.Score := 9;

  // Check for lower score than Gemma's 
  i := FindLowerScore(RecentScores, CurrentScore.Score);

  if i = -1 then
    WriteLn('No lower score found!')
  else
  begin
    // We have a lower score in the array. Update that one
    // with our new score.
    RecentScores[i].Name := CurrentScore.Name;
    RecentScores[i].Score := CurrentScore.Score;
    PrintScores('After', RecentScores);
  end;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: Thanks Ken...this is a nice solution. I wonder what the value of Score is, when the game is firstly compiled...for if it's not null,i.e. Zero, there will never be a new minimum score.  But i'm hedging my bets in guessing that it is created as 'null'. Thanks

Comment: @user3396486: You wouldn't need to do any of this when the game is first compiled, because you don't need to find the lowest score until you have at least two scores to compare, which means you'll always have at least one score to pass into the function and one in the Scores array. Using `Low` and `High` for the loop boundaries means it will work with any number of entries in `Scores`. IOW, you don't call `FindLowestScore` until you've played at least two games, because the first score is automatically lowest (and highest) score.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i used, following your advice...

```
Procedure UpdateRecentScores(Var RecentScores : TRecentScores; Score : Integer);
  Var
    PlayerName : String;
    Count : Integer;
    FoundSpace : Boolean;
  Begin
    PlayerName := GetPlayerName;
    FoundSpace := False;
    Count := 1;
    While Not FoundSpace And (Count <= NoOfRecentScores)
      Do If RecentScores[Count].Name = ''
           Then
             begin
               FoundSpace := True;
               RecentScores[Count].Name := PlayerName;
               RecentScores[Count].Score := Score;
             end
           Else Count := Count + 1;
    If Not FoundSpace
      Then
        Begin
          SortRecentScores(RecentScores); // sort them into order of score
          if score > RecentScores[NoOfRecentScores].Score then
            begin
              RecentScores[NoOfRecentScores].Name:= PlayerName;
              RecentScores[NoOfRecentScores].Score:= Score;
            end;
        End;

  End;
```

Comment: Hmm, I think it still fails the example from my answer (when the best scores are `[('Tim', 14), ('Derek', 12), ('Susan', 7), ('Don', 5)]`, and we play as `('Bert', 9)`. What I'd suggest is to change `If RecentScores[Count].Name = ''` into `If (RecentScores[Count].Name = '') or (RecentScores[Count].Score < Score)`. This way, it handles both cases: empty slot and a slot worse than our score. The `If Not FoundSpace ...` part is probably not needed then.

Comment: I tried your test data on mine, and it works fine. thanks Gassa